# Redis Streams - XREAD with pattern matching or stream partitioning

Tags: redis

I have a use case that seems suited to Redis Streams (need a slightly durable pub-sub + queue), except for one feature.

Is there a way to have XREAD pattern match streams, similar to how PSUBSCRIBE works?

If not, what would be the best way to have (>10000) streams that can each be read by a separate consumer, but can also as a group be read by a single consumer? I am leaning away from some sort of stream partitioning because MAXLEN ~ would be useful. If possible, I would like to avoid storing the data in more than one place.

Some approaches I thought of:

1. Keep all stream keys in a hash and append them to XREAD command in a Lua script (seems expensive to build such a long command?).
2. One extra stream to keep keys of streams that have received an update in the current tick.

Comment: [XREAD](https://redis.io/commands/xread/) does not do any sort of pattern matching. You'll need to do this yourself in code. Have you looked at using [consumer groups](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/streams-tutorial/#consumer-groups)? I think they'll help you in what you are trying to build.

Comment: As far as I understand, aren't consumer groups similar to a load balancer in that one stream can be sent to different consumers to serve? I was looking for vice versa.

Comment: More accurately, they act as a pointer to what has been read and processed for one or more consumers. If you need a single consumer (i.e. a group of one) to keep track of what it has read, they might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but i was rather looking for a way to group streams rather than consumers.